# Session_start conflicts with gpg exec

Tags: php, session, gnupg

I am experiencing a puzzling conflict with the session_start() command when used in conjuction with an exec() command that is calling gpg to encrypt a file.

```
$output =  exec("gpg --batch --passphrase asdf --symmetric --output ../files/test/uploads/smalltext.txt.gpg ../files/test/uploads/smalltext.txt 2>&1" ,$test);
print_r($test);     
exit;
```

This code above will work

```
session_start();        
$output =  exec("gpg --batch --passphrase asdf --symmetric --output ../files/test/uploads/smalltext.txt.gpg ../files/test/uploads/smalltext.txt 2>&1" ,$test);
print_r($test);     
exit;
```

This code will not work, it will state that

**gpg: can't open ../files/test/uploads/smalltext.txt**

**gpg: symmetric encryption of ../files/test/uploads/smalltext.txt failed: No such file or directory**

Currently the only work around I have is to call session_destroy(); and also set $_SESSION = array(); thus resetting it, calling the exec, and then re-setting all of my Session information.

Comment: May be a silly question, but I'll ask it anyway: Is `session_start();` include in all files? Are there any other files involved when executing?

Comment: Currently the test file I am running comprises of only the above lines of code for testing purposes, nothing else, no other includes at all.